# Deploying VB.NET application on a network share to minimize traffic

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment

I am relatively new to .net and looking for a method to deploy on a network share where the server will do most of the heavy lifting much like a terminal server.  The main purpose is to reduce the amount of network traffic over a slow connection between locations.  I have looked at the ClickOnce and it seems to rely on the client for most of the work in that situation.  Also asp.net is not a possibility as I need the rich client development environment for my app.

Comment: Have you considered a silverlight app?

Comment: There is always remote desktop. Other than that, I think Citrix has some proprietary solutions to that, but I don't believe they are free.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce network traffic then unless the application is doing something one off or relies heavily on a server data source your best off using clickOnce or a windows installer as the initial transfer cost is much less then the lifetime cost of any system that preforms most of the work on the server.

If your application does depend heavily on some sort of bandwidth intensive data connection to server but require a native client environment and networking is a real issue then it may be worth splitting you application into a thin client that communicates with the server for processing. This would involve careful consideration of the communication protocol.

Comment: Definitely. The question makes very little sense...In order to reduce the network traffic, he wants to run the app off of a network share? That's going to have the exact *opposite* effect.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have confusing description, as one comment pointed. If you want server to do heavy lifting and client do some light UI - you can create Win form App with connection to Web Service or WCF on the server. You can do Web API for that matter. You can do remoting. 
But there will be connection and traffic no matter what.

Or, just like someone said, app runs in cloud farm and people log via remote connection.